# low bandwidth to internet on single devcie / high to NAS

Tags: routing, lan

We have a house with many rooms, each floor connected via a switch and the switches connected to a main switch, which connects to a NAS and our router (see [our routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy6gw.png) for a map).

When transfering files from PC A to/from the NAS I get full Gbit speed. Meanwhile traffic to the internet (not from) is limited to around 1/50th of the speed since two days (full speed before).

Files from PC B (or any other PC) to/from NAS / internet are at full speed.

PCs / Routers have been restarted, any Ideas what could cause this?

Comment: 1/50th of the normal Internet speed, or 1/50th of local gigabit speed? confirm that no proxy is configured, and confirm whether the browser is slow while "connecting to" or "loading". if the issue is connecting to, inspect the DNS configuration for the box, as it may be pointing to a very bad DHCP server.

Comment: @FrankThomas: 1/50th of the internet Speed (have: 150Mbit, get: 3Mbit). No Proxy. Not only the browser is slow, Speedtest (speedtest.net), ftp-filetransfers etc are all the same. DNS is google 8.8.8.8

Comment: I have had problems with speedtest.net before that made me think I had a problem, at the least, ensure you test against another reliable speed testing site. I would check network drivers and any QOS on PC-A, and ensure there is no anomalous internet traffic/connection coming in or out of PC-A. You don't mention OS version, but I seem to recall having to turn off a windows-10 feature that, by default, is set up to be a "torrent-like" share server for updates, both public and private

Comment: You can probably eliminate bad cables and uplink port problems based on your description of the setup.